# Should I enable backports?

Tags: backport

Why and when one should backport software packages in a Ubuntu LTS release? 
Is that make sense to enable backports repository in a non-LTS release?

To my understanding some bug fixes never get included in the LTS? Why is that? Isn't that bad for user experience?

Comment: What bug fixes are yoy specifically referring to?

Comment: @xangua not one in particular. I've seen several on launchpad .. and faced such issues with programs like brasero